# For what $\alpha$ is the series uniformly convergent on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

The problem is stated as:

> Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)}$ is uniformly convergent on $[0, \infty)$ for $\alpha = 2$.

*I thought I might challenge myself a bit, so from hereon, I'll try to show for what $\alpha$ in general, that this series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.*

**My attempt**

Let $u_n(x) := \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)}$. We want to use Weierstrass M Test, in order to do this, we want to find $\sup_{x\in[0,\infty)} u_n(x)$ Observe that $\alpha \geq 0$ in order to have continuity at $ x=0$. Let's work with $\alpha \geq 0$ from hereon.

Taking the derivative, we get: $u'_n(x) = \frac{x^{\alpha - 1}\sqrt{n}[\alpha n^2+(\alpha-3)x^3]}{\sqrt{n}(n^2+x^3)^2}$

Obseve that $u_n(x)$ becomes a decreasing function for a certain x - value, let's call it $\hat{x}$ if we let $\alpha < 3$. For $\alpha \geq 3$ we have that $u_n(x)$ are monotonically increasing as functions. In that case, we can't find a supremum of our $u_n(x)$'s, where we wouldn't be able to apply Weierstrass M Test.

Solving for $x$ in the case that $\alpha < 3$, we get that we have a maximum at $\hat{x} = (\frac{\alpha}{3-\alpha}n^2)^{1/3}$

Hence, we have that: $M_n(x) := \sup_{x\in[0,\infty)} |u_n(x)| = |u_n(\hat{x})| =  |\frac{(\frac{\alpha}{3-\alpha}n^2)^{1/3})^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+(\frac{\alpha}{3-\alpha}n^2))}|$ which asymptotically behaves as $n^{2\alpha/3-5/2}$ and for which we set $2\alpha/3-5/2<-1$ in order to apply Weierstrass M test. Thus, we get that $\alpha < 9/4$, and with what we find above, we decude that we have uniform convergence for $\alpha \in [0, 9/4)$

I'd be glad if you could share any tips if you find anything wrong in the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Technically, one problem with your reasoning is that a sum may fail the Weierstrass M-test but still converge uniformly. That is, if you were trying to find all $\alpha$ such that the sum converges uniformly.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. So if it does pass WMT, it does with certainty converge uniformly. But the opposite doesn't have to be true, meaning, we might have uniform convergence but not passing WMT. Basically no equivalence? Am I right?

Comment: Yeah. Check out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3017989/converse-of-weierstrass-m-test-counterexample-to-the-statement,

Comment: Thanks! I read in the comments that it's necessary to have absolute convergence in order to use the converse of WMT. Is this statement true? Since it's then very easy to show that in my case.

Comment: Good question. Actually that fails too, and the counterexample given is absolutely convergent.

Comment: Okay! I see, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OP approach is good but here is a somewhat more complete analysis.

Note that the sum always converges since it can be bounded by $\leq c n^{-2}$ for some $c$ (depending on $x$).

One way to tackle the problem of uniform convergence is to consider the largest value per summand.

First, we can easily discard $\alpha \geq 3.$ Indeed, uniform convergence *signifies* that the sequence $\gamma_p = \sup\limits_{x \in [0, \infty)} \sum\limits_{n \geq p} \dfrac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n}(n^2 + x^3)}$ obeys $\gamma_p \to 0.$ Clearly $\gamma_p \geq \sup\limits_{x \in [0, \infty)} \dfrac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{p} (p^2 + x^3)}.$ If $\alpha = 3,$ the right hand side  equals 1 and if $\alpha > 3$ the right hand side is unbounded. *Therefore, $\alpha < 3$.*

Consider $u = u_\beta = \dfrac{x^\alpha}{\beta + x^3}.$ Then $u$ is maximised at $x = \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{\alpha \beta}{3 - \alpha}}.$ And considering anything but $\beta$ a constant, we see that $u \leq \hat{u} := u\left( \sqrt[3]{\dfrac{\alpha \beta}{3 - \alpha}}\right) \asymp \beta^{-(1 - \frac{\alpha}{3})}$ where $X \asymp Y$ means that the $aX \leq Y \leq b X$ for some "universal constants" $a$ and $b$ (the constants depend on $\alpha$ but not on $\beta$). Then,
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n}(n^2 + x^3)} \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{\hat{u}_{n^2}}{\sqrt{n}} \asymp \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \dfrac{n^{-(2 - \frac{2\alpha}{3})}}{\sqrt{n}} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty n^{-\zeta}
$$
where $\zeta = 2 + \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{2\alpha}{3}.$ The right hand side converges when $\zeta > 1$ which entails $\alpha < \dfrac{9}{4}.$ *Therefore, there there is uniform convergence for $0 \leq \alpha < \dfrac{9}{4}.$*

The question *remains open* for $\dfrac{9}{4} \leq \alpha < 3.$ However, I suspect there will *not* be uniform convergence. Note that the proof gives that the maximums of each summand are at $c n^{\frac{2}{3}}$ for some $c$ depending solely on $\alpha.$ This says that the tail $\gamma_p$ will always take into account the worst-case scenario for an infinite number of summands, and the function $x \mapsto \dfrac{x^\alpha}{\beta + x^3}$ is quite flat for $\alpha < 3$ but close to 3.

Answer (score 3):

I believe OP already showed, using the Weierstrass M-test, that the series converges uniformly in $x \in [0, \infty)$ if $\alpha < \frac{9}{4}$. So, I will show that the series does not converge uniformly if $\alpha \geq \frac{9}{4}$.

Note that the series converges uniformly in $x \in [0, \infty)$ if and only if the tail series converges to $0$ uniformly in $x \in [0, \infty)$:

$$ \bbox[border:1px blue;padding:7px;background-color:azure;]{\lim_{N\to\infty} \sup_{x\geq 0} \Biggl( \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)} \Biggr) = 0.} $$

Now suppose $\alpha \geq \frac{9}{4}$. Then by noting that $n \mapsto \frac{x^{9/4}}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)}$ is decreasing in $n$, for $x \geq 1$ we get

$$ \int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{x^{9/4}}{\sqrt{s}(s^2+x^3)} \, \mathrm{d}s
\leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{x^{9/4}}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)}
\leq \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)}. $$

However, by substituting $s = x^{3/2}t$,

$$ \int_{N}^{\infty} \frac{x^{9/4}}{\sqrt{s}(s^2+x^3)} \, \mathrm{d}s
= \int_{N/x^{3/2}}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}(t^2+1)} \, \mathrm{d}t
\to
C \qquad \text{as } x \to \infty,
$$

where $C = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{t}(t^2+1)} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$. Combining altogether, it follows that

$$ \sup_{x\geq 0} \Biggl( \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)} \Biggr)
\geq \lim_{x\to\infty} \sum_{n=N}^{\infty} \frac{x^\alpha}{\sqrt{n} (n^2+x^3)}
\geq C $$

for any $N$ and therefore the series does not converge uniformly in $[0,\infty)$ for $\alpha \geq \frac{9}{4}$.